# Facebook type slide menu for UITabBarcontroller with custom button in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement Facebook type slide menu for UITabBarController, which has four tabs(Screens) and also this side menu should appear when we click on Custom `UIButton` at the top of each screen. I tried some of the open source slide menus like `ECSlidingViewController`, `PKRevealController`, `JTRevealSidebarDemo`, and `SASlideMenu`, but none of them provided this functionality without **`UINavigationController`**. Could anyone guide me how to achieve above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Those open source slide menus are often complicated and not well built, or built for older versions. This is what I did

Create a custom button, and then animate it to slide left to right or right to left, off the scree to on the scree to make it look like its expanding, etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti check out the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535455/ios-retractable-menu